# How to tell if an ssh session is using x forwarding (if it was run with -X or -Y)

Tags: ssh, forwarding, x11, x11forwarding

For a given ssh session, is there a way to tell if it has x-forwarding enabled?  I.e. you don't know if the session was established with `ssh username@address` or with `ssh -X username@address`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple indication is to look to see if a valid looking DISPLAY variable is set.  If no display is set, you can be almost certain forwarding is not working properly.

```
$ export | grep DISPLAY
declare -x DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"
```